# jquery date picker - specific months

Tags: jquery, user-interface, datepicker

Is there a way to set the jquery ui date picker to only show a couple of specific months? For example I'm setting this up on a form so when a user is inquiring about availability the only months that show up on the jquery date picker are June / July?

Comment: I was looking for this, too, and stumbled across the following. Works brilliantly, for me! :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17304900/jquery-ui-datepicker-limit-certain-months-not-a-range-of-months

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can restrict dates by placing a max/min:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#min-max

But I don't think you can't pick & choose specific months
i.e. Allow May & July, but disable June

Answer (score 1):

Try this one also: very cool month and year picker. you can select only specific months:
http://tinytools.codesells.com/PeriodSelector

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [maxDate](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-maxDate) and minDate options.