# jQuery UI datepicker: limit certain months (not a range of months)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am looking to restrict the months for the `jQuery UI datepicker`.

For example, I want to prevent users from selecting april, august and October in any given year.  I have my months in an array of numbers, eg  4,8,10.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope you tried something, but I have a few spare minutes so f I understand correctly you want to disable the use of some months.

You can use the [`beforeShowDay`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShowDay) event of jQuery UI Datepicker and check if a day is active or not based on its month and check if is in the array.

To check the array I use the jQuery [`inArray`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) method.

### beforeShowDay

> Default: null A function that takes a date as a parameter and must
>   return an array with: [0]: true/false indicating whether or not this
>   date is selectable [1](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShowDay): a CSS class name to add to the date's cell or
>   "" for the default presentation [2](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/): an optional popup tooltip for
>   this date The function is called for each day in the datepicker before
>   it is displayed.

### jQuery.inArray

> Description: Search for a specified value within an array and return
>   its index (or -1 if not found).

Code sample:

```
monthArray = [0, 3, 6]

$(function () {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        beforeShowDay: function (date) {
            //getMonth()  is 0 based
            if ($.inArray(date.getMonth(), monthArray) > -1) {
                return [false, ''];
            }
            return [true, ''];
        }
    });
});
```

Here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/APP5N/